# Disable tool tip text of components in an iframe(different domain)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, tooltip

I have an `iframe`(of a different domain not under my control) loaded on a page and it has annoying tool tip texts on its buttons
so is there a way in which i can use `jquery` `js` or `css` in any way so that i disable that tool tip text or tool tip text on whole of the page??

**note:** The page in the `iframe` uses `https` so i when i tried injecting scripts in an `iframe`(using jquery) to simply strip the title tag the browser dosent allows me to do that it gives an `http` vs `https` protocol error.

so basically i want a script to run on the parent window to disable all possible tool tip text...

Please Some one help me on this.. stuck since a long time....

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as you do not get access to the code of an external domain through javascript, regardless of if the doain is `http` or `https`. This is a security feature of all browsers and cannot be circumvented.

Comment: well actually u can do that... i did that this security feature was removed in the new js and jq i achieved this through jquery.....all i want is to suppress all tooltips through a script running on the parent window

Comment: because i can do it only with http not https that the problem.